# PowerShell -as [Type] syntax

Tags: powershell

I found in the Get-FileHash function (source: Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility.psm1) this statement:

```
$hasherType = "System.Security.Cryptography.${Algorithm}CryptoServiceProvider" -as [Type]
```

my questions are:

1. what is the difference (if any) writing "-as [Type]" or just simply "[Type]$xxxx?
2. ${Algorithm} could be defined as well: $($Algorithm)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what is the difference (if any) writing `-as [Type]` or just simply `[Type]$xxxx`?

The [`-as` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_type_operators?view=powershell-7.3#-as-operator) is heavily inspired by the so-called unchecked conversion operator from C# (corresponding to the C# keyword [`as`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#as-operator)) - the operation will simply evaluate to `$null` in case of conversion failure. This behavior differs significantly from a regular `[type]$value` cast, which will throw an exception on failure.

Testing for `$null` is usually faster than capturing and handling an exception, so this can be useful in situations where you expect *some* values not to conform to a given type:

```
$bunchOfMixedValues |ForEach-Object {
  $thing = $_ -as [TargetType]
  if ($null -ne $thing) {
    # process $thing
  }
  else {
    # no need to care about invalid input, do nothing
  }
}
```

> `${Algorithm}` could be defined as well: `$($Algorithm)`?

The end result would be the same, yes.

`${...}` represents the exact same element as `$...` - a variable path literal expression. You can think of the `{` and `}` brackets as *quotation marks* for variable expressions, in other words they *qualify the boundary* of the variable name - so PowerShell knows not to attempt to expand `$AlgorithmCryptoServiceProvider` instead.

It's therefore safer to use the `${...}` syntax when generating code for example, which is why you'll see it in lots of Microsoft-authored modules.